# Unable to modify XML file in by using servlet

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to modify a xml file located in my apache tomcat directory.

I am using this code to modify:

```
String filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("")
            + File.separator +"\\xml_server.xml";
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new File(filePath));

        nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        Node menu = doc.getFirstChild();

            Element item = doc.createElement("item");
            menu.appendChild(item);

            Element id = doc.createElement("id");
            id.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(nList.getLength()+2)));
            item.appendChild(id);

            Element name = doc.createElement("name");
            name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(fileName));
            item.appendChild(name);

            Element version = doc.createElement("version");
            version.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("1"));
            item.appendChild(version);

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                    .newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filePath));
            transformer.transform(source, result);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Here is the error which I'm face while running this:

type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
fr.studec.FileUploadServlet.updateXml(FileUploadServlet.java:131)
fr.studec.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:106)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From exception it is clear that the class `org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal` cannot be found.`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` occurs when a class is not available or cannot be found at runtime.
This class is part of `Xalan and Xerces APIs`
There are many possible reasons for thisnto occur.

Below links to previously asked questions can make it clear

[[AppEngine Error [ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234201/appengine-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234201/appengine-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal)

[[NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515333/noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515333/noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal)