# ElementTraversal cannot be found by batik dom

Tags: maven, svg, eclipse-rcp, batik

I creating an eclipse rcp application, which has to generate SVG files.

For that purpose, I use `apache batik` libraries.  To get libraries as plugins I use `p2-maven-plugin`. Generally speaking, I have no problems at compile time.

When it comes to runtime, despite adding all necessary (at least I think) plugins when I call the method which does conversion to SVG file I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal cannot be found by org.apache.xmlgraphics.batik-dom_1.8.0
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 51 more
```

How it is possible to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515333/noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal

Comment: I included xml-api 1.4.01 in my project.
But as for the first answer, I not installed any jetty.
Any suggestions?