# "Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class" error when adding xml-apis-1.4.01.jar as a dependency

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) which lists `xml-apis-1.4.01.jar` as a dependency. Though whenever I include this file in the `libs/` directory I get the following error:

```
Error: trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":
Error: Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
...
```

Could anyone help me resolve this.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add full logcat of error

Comment: Edited the title in an attempt to make it clearer.

It may be useful to include extra details, such as which version of `Java` & `HtmlUnit`, how you are running the code to get the error (via IDE or console), and exactly which `libs/` directory you place the jar in.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't put .jars into `libs` folder, as you will quickly run into dependency hell. Use gradle build system for that. In your `app` module `build.gradle` file declare such dependency:

```
compile ('net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.23') {
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
```

And everything will build correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I followed the above steps but now I am getting new errors - `  ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
   File1: /home/darknight/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0/9bb329db1cfc4e22462c9d6b43a8432f5850e92c/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
   File2: /home/darknight/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/22b4c53dd9b6761024258de8f9240c3dce6ea368/httpmime-4.5.2.jar`

Comment: Check [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673625/android-gradle-plugin-0-7-0-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk) or add another `exlude module: 'httpmime'`

Comment: Thanks! I followed that solution..and now I am stuck at another error - `Error:(106, 48) error: cannot access ElementTraversal
class file for org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal not found` Could you help me with this one?

Comment: Firstly, look for the solution on [Google](http://google.com/) or [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/). This is the second problem you experienced that has been already solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515333/noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal